# When do elite mobs reset to full HP?

Tags: diablo-iii

When do elite mobs in D3 reset to full HP? Sometimes it happened right after dying the first time. Sometimes it doesn't happen at all and sometimes it happens after dying a few times.

In any case there was almost no time to walk back from the checkpoint. So I wonder if it's random, just bugged or if there is some logic behind it.

Comment: I guess it only appears random, but in fact there will be reson behind this, for example the mobs might have different view distances where they chase you, depending on where the minions are etc. But thats just my guess.

Comment: I would guess it's also different depending on which mode you are on. I noticed in Inferno mobs regenerate health rapidly, which you can notice right after you die, their health starts regenerating.

Comment: Elite and normal mobs (try it with the zombies at the beginning of Act 1) regen when they are out of combat (e.g. player dies), or when the player is out of range, for a certain amount of time (~10s for elites, might be longer for normal mobs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you die, assuming you have no companion, team mate, or quest follower still there fighting the minions, the minions will cease fighting and group up and their timer will start.  The minions will very subtlety flash, about once a second for roughly 10 seconds? (I'll have to get back to you with an exact answer on that..)

If you have a quest follower though, they will some times stay and continue fighting the mobs, keeping them from resetting and beginning their heal timer.  This can screw you with their enrage timer though, if you take to long they enrage doing more damage and they put a debuff on you dealing damage over time.

Addition:  I've been farming inferno and noted that some of the elite spawns that don't group up tightly, like the flying bugs, don't heal properly, we came back after a minute + and they were still at the same hp level.  While this was helpful, I can see how it adds confusion to the mobs healing characteristics.